# Error in v3.22 while creating GMap Lat/Lng Object using getCenter()

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

**EDIT: This is/was a confirmed bug in the experimental v3.22, but, what you are about to read is a pretty bad implementation that I ended up finding in a legacy code.**

In the new [JS v3.22 GMap API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference) running the following code yields an error:

```
new google.maps.LatLng(map.getCenter());
```

The error I get is the following:

```
xb {message: "in property lat: not a number", name: "InvalidValueError", stack: "Error↵    at Error (native)↵    at new xb (https:/…ject.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:664:21)"}
(anonymous function)    @   main.js:16
M   @   main.js:20
(anonymous function)    @   VM744:2
InjectedScript._evaluateOn  @   VM601:875
InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap @   VM601:808
InjectedScript.evaluate @   VM601:664
```

I did a little bit of research and ended up finding that **this doesn't happen when I run the same code in a previous version (<=3.21)**, for example using:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.21&sensor=false
```

Here is my map initialization:

```
<div id="map" data-latitude="" data-longitude=""></div>
function loadMap() {
  var options = {
    zoom: 12,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    scrollwheel: 1
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
  var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(18.48970297360103,-69.89810943603516);
  map.setCenter(mapCenter,12);
}
```

JSFiddle with v3.22: https://jsfiddle.net/nsy3Lugk/1/

JSFiddle with v3.21: https://jsfiddle.net/nsy3Lugk/2/

I know this probably should be reported in the JS API, but, I can't seem to open a new issue in https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list (I get an 400 error response while trying to submit the issue and everything looks outdated there).

If you can answer any of the following question it would be really helpful:

- Is anyone else facing the same issue (or can reproduce the error)?
- What might be causing this issue (no major version change, so it should have backward compatibility)?
- Where is the correct place to report this kind of bug/problem?

Comment: Possibly related issue in the issue tracker [Issue 8809: (Maps API V3) no longer accepts null values new google.maps.LatLng()[https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8809]

Comment: How are your setting the center of your map?  There are two required parameters center and zoom.

Comment: You are right @geocodezip, I endedup missing that part of the initialization. See my edit. Also the center is changed dynamically using searchs, but, this part doesn't really matter since in v3.22 it doesn't work either after a search set nor with the initialization and in v3.21 it works boths (with the initialization and after a search that endsup setting the center).

Comment: @geocodezip the problem seems to be that map.getCenter() is yielding a different object in v3.22. That is pretty weird taking into account that it's only a PATCH version change (not even e MINOR version).

Comment: Related issue on the issue tracker: [Issue 8809: (Maps API V3) no longer accepts null values new google.maps.LatLng()](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8809). v3.22 is currently the experimental version, that is not feature stable and can change or break at any time.

Comment: As a matter of curiosity, why does your call to `map.setCenter` have two arguments?  [`map.setCenter(mapCenter,12);`]  That looks like an artifact left over from v2 of the API.

Comment: @geocodezip thanks for the link! I think it might be related to some changes in the setCenter function. I will try to report the issue there :)

Comment: Can you provide an example that exhibits the issue?  [The "initialization code" you posted in your question works fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/w58jdztg/).  This: `new google.maps.LatLng(map.getCenter());` shouldn't ever have worked, the `google.maps.LatLng` constructor expects two numbers as arguments, not a `google.maps.LatLng` object.

Comment: @geocodezip this code belongs to a legacy app, I guess it might be because of that. Will take a look into that, thanks!

Comment: @geocodezip Let me see if I can reproduce the issue into a JSFiddle (the JS for the map is pretty big, so I might have forgot something)! Will try to get back to you soon :). Thanks for the help anyways!

Comment: @geocodezip here is a JSFiddle where I was able to reproduce the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/nsy3Lugk/1/ and https://jsfiddle.net/nsy3Lugk/2/ using the v3.21 where the issue doesn't show up :)

Comment: [Your "non-working fiddle" works for me if I add a size for the map](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/nsy3Lugk/3/).  I do see the error message: `Uncaught InvalidValueError: in property lat: not a number`, but that makes sense as a `google.maps.LatLng` object is not a number.  The ["working fiddle"](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/nsy3Lugk/4/) (which is also missing a map size), just doesn't report the problem.  What are you trying to use that `new google.maps.LatLng(map.getCenter())` for?

Comment: @geocodezip yeah! I just realized how stupid that code is, getCenter returns a LatLng obj. Just disregard this, I guess. Anyways, thanks for the help and sorry for the time.

Comment: @geocodezip by the way, what the coded endedup trying to do was adding a marker using the created LatLng Obj :) That is what wasn't working. I guess just legacy hell code stuff!

Comment: That (`new google.maps.LatLng(map.getCenter())`) isn't a valid `google.maps.LatLng`  that shouldn't have ever worked.

Comment: @geocodezip that is what I'm asking myself now, how on earth did that work before? Haha!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't help with that specific error but I just fixed a similar issue. I have a client that's been using this library for a long time, and today they said they're not getting maps. After checking everything locally it turns out I passing elements from a String array for Lat/Lng values, which the API accepted until a couple days ago.

The remedy for me was to add zero to the Lat and Lng in the constructor of a `new google.maps.LatLng(lat+0,lng+0)`.

Correct link about this issue is https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8809 - the comment by @geocodezip includes a trailing bracket, but that is the right issue and I added a comment to confirm the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your input! The link was really helpful, but seems like the problem is within the map.getCenter() that is yielding different results.

Comment: In the referenced bug report, Google confirms that they just broke the current experimental version by removing support for objects. I'm guessing that will be fixed before production. The solution would be to specify the release of the library that you want with `v=3.20` until the next release goes production.

Comment: Yes! I'm already using the v3.21 and that fixes the problem in production, I just wanted to make sure that when v3.22 got released I wouldn't have problems. In the end, in my case, creating a new LatLng Obj from another LatLng didn't make ANY sense (and it's not even documented). Because of that reason I prefer to just use getCenter() directly :)! Anyways, your answer was helpful so I'm upvoting it.

Comment: Thanks for upvoting my answer but marking your own as accepted. It's OK to use GetCenter. That wasn't the problem. The problem was that the release changed, causing your valid code to fail. All three of your questions were answered here.

Answer (score 0):

In the end what `map.getCenter()` does is return a LatLng obj, so there is no point on creating a new LatLng obj using another LatLng!

I guess I ended up "tunnel visioning" in the "it worked in the previous version!" argument.

In my case that code was used to create a new LatLng Obj to create a marker, so I just removed the `new google.maps.LatLng();` part and used directly `map.getCenter()` to create the marker, which should be the logical thing to do.

For some reason this used to work in the <=3.21 API but isn't either an expected behaviour nor documented/supported.

Even though,  as stated by other users, there is/was a confirmed bug in the experimental v3.22 (https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8809) that might have caused this issue (see the accepted answer for more info).